# Automatically updating graph that only picks out information per date

Tags: charts

Basically what I need is a formula to look up a date in column A (yesterday), return data from Column K and M to create a graph. Column A can have 0-3 rows per day that need to go into the graph. I need the formula to pull ALL data for yesterday, not just the last entry.

Comment: Welcome to SU. Please clarify your question. What software (and version) are you using to create a graph? What is the best solution you've devised so far? What do you want the graph to show (such as, "daily values over the last month")?

Comment: Sorry I am new to this. I tried to add a picture to explain but I am not allowed. Sheet1 is a machine "Press1" and for that machine the columns have date, shift, scrap %, units produced, efficiency... Everyday the previous days data is entered, i would like a Daily Graph, meaning i want the graph to only show the last date entered.

Comment: At this time i just manually update the graph. I understand how to make a graph auto update but i need it to not just update new row added but if there is no data for that day i need it to show 0... sometimes all 3 shifts will work and sometimes not, so there can be 0 - 3 lines added every morning. I'd like the graph to show Shift ABC and the Date for scrap and efficiency.

Comment: If three lines are added for a day, do you only care about the most recent? Or do you want to graph the sum of the three?

Comment: Have you tried a Scatter chart? Where does that fall short?

Comment: please edit your question based on your comment responses. You'll get the best answers if readers can see the core issue immediately upon reading your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To keep things straight, I would recommend splitting up the equations.

**Step 1** is to find the first row with the target date (yesterday):

```
=MATCH(TODAY()-1,A:A,0)
```

That gives you the row number of the first cell in column `A` that matches yesterday's date (`TODAY()-1`). Column `A` needs to be be in ascending order. You can then [name the cell](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Define-and-use-names-in-formulas-2d9abce7-42cf-4a21-a6b4-f02786f690b7#bmquickly_name_a_cell_or_range_of_cells) `Yesterday`.

**Step 2** is to set up six cells to match the two columns and zero to three rows of results:

```
=IF(INDEX(A:A,Yesterday+2)=TODAY()-1,INDEX(K:K,Yesterday+2),"--")
```

In place of the two `+2` modifiers, you'll need `+0`, `+1`, and `+2` for the three possible rows. Swap `M:M` or any other column to pull the results from a column other than `K`. The `"--"` is what is returned if there is no entry for that row for that date. If you want this to be well-behaved when there are zero rows, wrap the whole equation in `=IFERROR(...,"--")`.

**Alternative answer:**

If you only want to match the most recent row, try the pattern `=INDEX(K:K,MATCH(TODAY()-1,A:A,1))`

This assumes that your dates are in column `A` and are sorted in ascending order. The `1` as the third argument for `INDEX` is the match type, and is what gives you the most recent row prior to `TODAY`, specified with `TODAY()-1`. That will be yesterday if there was an entry yesterday.

You can replace `TODAY()-1` with a cell reference where you can type in the date you want.

Comment: I just noticed that you want to pull all three rows that match the date. I'll have to change my answer to match that.